# loading a file into a richtextbox

Tags: c#

Right now my code is set so that when this button is clicked, it opens a select file dialog and allows the person to choose which file to open.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
            }
        }
```

However - I have changed my program so that the program simply outputs to a default file like so -

```
public void CreateInventory(CreateInventory createinventory)
{
    try
    {
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream
        ("CreateInventory.bin", FileMode.Create,
        FileAccess.Write);
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(fileStream, createinventory);
        fileStream.Close();
    }
    catch (ItemNotFoundException)
    {
        throw new ItemNotFoundException("Output not created - see logs");
    }
}
```

How do I switch the button so that it loads that file directly, instead of asking the user to choose a file to load?

Answer (score 0):

I do not exactly understand what your problem is, tell me more about what are you want to do.

But I recommend to change your code:

```
public void CreateInventory(CreateInventory createinventory)
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("CreateInventory.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(fileStream, createinventory);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ItemNotFoundException("Output not created - see logs", ex);
        }
    }
```

1. You should not catch an exception and re-throw the same exception - you lose precious information (e.g. stacktrace). If the exception is not correct in the view of a caller, you can wrap it, like I do in my code above.
2. It is very important to put a disposable (a class that implements `IDisposable`) class in a using statement.

**Why use 'Using'?**

A disposable class contains unmanaged resources (in this case a file handle) and they are not released like managed resources. You should release when you done with it. The using has another advantage: It calls `Dispose()` for you even when the scope ends or if an exception occurs. The file is released and other process may can get access to the file..